# Finding the closest index to a value in R

Tags: r, search, vector, indexing

I have a question about finding index values in a vector.

Let's say I have a vector as follows:

```
vector <- c(1,2,4,6,8,10)
```

And, let's say I have the value '5'. I would like to find the maximum index in "vector" such that it is less than or equal to the value 5. In the case of the example above, this index would be 3 (since 4 is less than or equal to 5). Similarly, if instead I had a vector such as:

```
vector <- c(1,2,4,5,6,8,10)
```

Then if I were to find a value less than or equal to 5, this index would now be 4 instead of 3.

However, I also want to find the *first* and *last* time this index occurs. For example, if I had a vector such as:

```
vector <- c(1,1,2,2,4,5,5,5,5,6,8,10)
```

Then the first time this index occurs would be 6 and the last time this index occurs would be 9.

Is there a short, one-line method which would allow me to perform this task? Up until now I have been using the function max(which(....)), however I find that this method is extremely inefficient for large datasets since it will literally list hundreds/thousands of values, so I would like to find a more efficient method if possible which can fit in one line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `vector` is sorted, see `?findInterval` -- calling it once with "left.open = TRUE" and once with "left.open = FALSE" should give the two indices (plus a bit of `if` manipulation to distinct `<` from `<=`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
min(max(which(vector <= 5)), min(which(vector == 5)))
```

First, it searches all indices where `vector` is less or equal to 5 with `which` function, then it takes the maximum one.

Second, it searches all indices where `vector` is equal to 5 and takes the minimum.

Third, it takes the first of these two indices

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do this such that the "min" (or "max") is inside the "which" function? I actually have a very similar code to that at the moment - the problem I'm having though is that I have an extremely large dataset, so what happens is that the "which" function returns thousands of values and then the "max" function then takes the maximum value of that. Since I'm iterating hundreds of times, this causes my program to run very slowly, so I'm looking for a more efficient method to do this task

Comment: For the `min` part, you can simply take `which(vector == 5)[1]` but I am not sure it would reduce runtime

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all those who replied, I actually found an extremely short, one-line method to do this by download a package `BBmisc`. It has functions called `which.last` and `which.first`, and they perform the actions I need. Thanks again for taking the time to reply, I appreciate it.

Comment: See here for the __c__ source of that function - https://github.com/berndbischl/BBmisc/blob/95a625fe0bd92413910f8c4f8f9c79c801a96af9/src/which_first.c#L14

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
my_ind <- function(vec, num){
  ind <- which.max(vec == num) # Check for equality first
  if(ind == 1L && vec[1L] != num){
    ind <- which.min(vec < num) - 1L
  }
  ind
}

my_ind(c(1,2,4,6,8,10), 5L) # 3
my_ind(c(1,2,4,5,6,8,10), 5L) # 4
my_ind(c(1,1,2,2,4,5,5,5,5,6,8,10), 5L) # 6
my_ind(c(5,8,10), 5L) # 1
my_ind(c(6,8,10), 5L) # 0 - returns 0 if all(vec > 5L)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a need for packages here. It seems like the construct `which(x == max(x[x <= 5]))` would work for you.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
which(x == max(x[x <= 5]))
# [1] 3

x <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10)
which(x == max(x[x <= 5]))
# [1] 4

x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 10)
which(x == max(x[x <= 5]))
# [1] 6 7 8 9
```

And to find the min/max index for multiples indices, use `head/tail`.

```
head(which(x == max(x[x <= 5])), 1)
# [1] 6
tail(which(x == max(x[x <= 5])), 1)
# [1] 9
```

Comment: Assuming I've understood the question