# Finding index of array of matrices, that is closest to each element of another matrix in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, vectorization, closest

I have an array Q which has size nquantiles by nfeatures by nfeatures. In this, essentially the slice Q[1,,] would give me the first quantile of my data, across all nfeatures by nfeatures of my data.

What I am interested in, is using another matrix M (again of size nfeatures by nfeatures) which represents some other data, and asking the question to which quantile do each of the elements in M lie in Q.

What would be the quickest way to do this?

I reckon I could do double for loop across all rows and columns of the matrix M and come up with a solution similar to this: [Finding the closest index to a value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595028/finding-the-closest-index-to-a-value-in-r)

But doing this over all nfeatures x nfeatures values will be very inefficient. I am hoping that there might exist a vectorized way of approaching this problem, but I am at a lost as to how to approach this.

Here is a reproducible way of the *slow* way I can approach the problem with O(N^2) complexity.

```
#Generate some data
set.seed(235)
data             = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
list_of_matrices = list(matrix(data = data[1:25], ncol = 5, nrow = 5),
                        matrix(data = data[26:50], ncol = 5, nrow = 5),
                        matrix(data = data[51:75], ncol = 5, nrow = 5),
                        matrix(data = data[76:100], ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
#Get the quantiles  (5 quantiles here)
Q <- apply(simplify2array(list_of_matrices), 1:2, quantile, prob = c(seq(0,1,length = 5)))
#dim(Q)
#Q should have dims nquantiles by nfeatures by nfeatures

#Generate some other matrix M (true-data)
M             = matrix(data = rnorm(n = 25, mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

#Loop through rows and columns in M to find which index of the array matches up closest with element M[i,j]
results = matrix(data = NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
for (i in 1:nrow(M)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(M)) {
    true_value = M[i,j]
    #Subset Q to the ith and jth element (vector of nqauntiles)
    quantiles  = Q[,i,j]
    results[i,j]    = (which.min(abs(quantiles-true_value)))
  }
}
'''
```

Comment: Will this operation be performed just once, for a single M, or will it be performed many times on Q for different M?

Comment: M stays constant for a given Q

Comment: Could we have a reproducible example of input and output please?

Comment: I think you will find `cut` useful, since you already have your quantiles. And quantiles are nothing more than break points.

Comment: Yes I am aware of 'cut' functionality to get the intervals/endpoints however, I don't see how that will help me vectorize over the elements in M (maybe it does, I just don't see it!)

Comment: `cut` accepts a matrix as an input.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that thanks. I am about to post the example with a reproducible example, either with the reproducible example/your own toy code would you mind writing up how to use cut in that fashion

Comment: Hi, I have added an example of the slow way to approach this problem, wondering if there is a more vectorised manner to approach this!